# Version Comparision of User Generated and Modified Content

Tags: user-interface, comparison, wiki-engine, user-generated-content

I'm working on a project constructing an online collaboration tool. Looking at Wikipedia, I noticed that user-generated **itterations of a page can easily be compared to each other**; the comparison highlights the differences.

**Conceptually, what would I need to implement to do pretty much exactly the same?**

Comment: Why can't you just use any of the already existing wiki engines for your collaboration tool?

Comment: The complexity of our tool goes a little further than that. Question is, depite that, are these engines any good? I don't want to create the millionth wiki.

Comment: Oh yes, there are *plenty* of good wiki engines. Don't reinvent the wheel. If you do, you might want to look at the edit viewer on SO, it sounds similar to what you are describing.

Comment: The SO edit view is almost exactly what I want to accomplish. That's based on a wiki engine?

Comment: @Kriem: yes, SO is a wiki. IIRC, it is custom built.

Comment: @Zifre (and lothar?): Good to know! Care to make it a real answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Composited from the good advice:*

**The easiest way is to just use any of the already existing wiki engines. There are *plenty* of good wiki engines. Don't reinvent the wheel.**

For example, StackOverflow itself is a custom built wiki. Look at the edit viewer on Stack Overflow to see how well its functionality meets the one described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a *versioned datastore* and a *diffing algorithm.*

Store versions of your resources by giving each resource a revision number. When a user edits a resource, instead of replacing the resource, save the edit as a new entry in your datastore with a new, higher revision number. When you want to retrieve the resource, return the one with the highest revision.

Instead of a revision number you could use timestamps. Not only do timestamps always increase, but the revision number itself could be used to identify when the resource was modified.

Choose a diff algorithm based on how you're storing the resources. Wikitext is usually linewise, so if users are editing that, it would make sense to use a linewise diff like the standard Unix `diff` utility. If the resources are XML, you may wish to find an XML-specific diff algorithm so that it would be clear to users where the differences are.